# Perl Array Values Access and Sum by each unique key

Tags: perl

```
# my code as follows
use strict;
use FileHandle;

my @LISTS       = ('incoming');
my $WORK        ="c:\";
my $OUT         ="c:\";

foreach my $list (@LISTS) {
    my $INFILE      = $WORK."test.dat";
    my $OUTFILE     = $OUT."TEST.dat";

    while (<$input>) {
        chomp;
        my($f1,$f2,$f3,$f4,$f5,$f6,$f7) = split(/\|/);
        push @sum, $f4,$f7;
    }

}
while (@sum) {
    my ($key,$value)=  {shift@sum, shift@sum};
    $hash{$key}=0;
    $hash{$key} += $value;
}
while my $key (@sum) {
    print $output2 sprintf("$key1\n");
    # print $output2 sprintf("$key ===> $hash{$key}\n");
}
close($input);
close($output);
```

I am getting errors Unintialized error at addition (+) If I use 2nd print
I get HASH(0x19a69451) values if I use 1st Print.
I request you  please correct me.

My output should be

```
unique Id ===> Total Revenue ($f4==>$f7)
```

Comment: Please format your code and post some sample lines of test.dat

Comment: Where do you open `$input`? Could you show what it contains? Why do you use `sprintf`? What is the content of `@sum` before the while loop? ...

Answer (score 5):

This is wrong:

```
"c:\";
```

Perl reads that as a string starting with `c:";\n...`.  Or in other words, it is a run away string.  You need to write the last character as `\\` to escape the `\` and prevent it from escaping the subsequent `"` character

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use parens instead of braces:

```
my ($key, $value) = (shift @sum, shift @sum);
```

You would get that `Unintialized error at addition (+)` warning if the `@sum` array has an odd number of elements.

See also [perltidy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perltidy).

Comment: Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at VPNData.pl line 140
, <GEN0> line 1173064.
This is my error. How to correct it

Answer (score 0):

You should not enter the second while loop :

```
while my $key (@sum) {
```

because the previous one left the array `@sum` empty.

You could change to:

```
while (<$input>) {
    chomp;
    my @tmp = split(/\|/);
    $hash{$tmp[3]} += $tmp[6];
}
print Dumper \%hash;
```

Comment: push @sum, $f4,$f7; I am trying to pass values $f4, $f7 using Push Also Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at VPNData.pl line 140
, <GEN0> line 1173064.
I am getting this error, How to correct it

Comment: Trying to get @sum from previous Push stmt